# How to troubleshoot "Failed to fetch slave info from Jenkins"

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server and a Jenkins slave and the slave won't connect to the server anymore.  The slave reports:

```
SEVERE: Failed to fetch slave info from Jenkins, HTTP response code: 500
```

The only thing unusual that happened was that the server got low on disk space and I had to do a docker volume prune and then restart it.  Now the slave won't reconnect.

The slave uses GitHub Auth to connect to the server.  Auth was set up just fine (has been working for a long time until yesterday) but something has stopped working and I'm not sure what it could be.

This error message doesn't really tell me much.  So, what else should I investigate to figure out what happened?  What other clues should I look for?

PS, everything's running in docker.

Jenkins is 2.150.2

Answer (score 0):

OK, so apparently GitHub changed their API recently and now the personal access token requires at least read:org to authenticate.  (Didn't used to!)  So the solution was to log into GitHub, edit the personal access token used by the slave to authenticate and add the `read:org` access scope.